# How to verify odom --> base_link is accurate or not？

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, base-link, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using AMCL and when I specify a goal to navigation, the pose of my robot drift.While AMCL need `odom --> base_link` tf and laserscan data,so how can I verify `odom --> base_link` is accurate or not？

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248348/how-to-verify-odom---%3E-base_link-is-accurate-or-not%EF%BC%9F/) by [Damo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26732/damo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Extracted from section 1.2 in the [navigation tuning guide](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide):

> Often, I'll have a lot of trouble
> getting a robot to localize correctly.
> It will constantly get lost and I'll
> spend a lot of time mucking with the
> parameters for AMCL only to find that
> the real culprit is the robot's
> odometry. As such, I always run two
> sanity checks to make sure that I
> believe the odometry of a robot.
>
> The first test checks how reasonable
> the odometry is for rotation. I open
> up rviz, set the frame to "odom,"
> display the laser scan the robot
> provides, set the decay time on that
> topic high (something like 20
> seconds), and perform an in-place
> rotation. Then, I look at how closely
> the scans match each other on
> subsequent rotations. Ideally, the
> scans will fall right on top of each
> other, but some rotational drift is
> expected, so I just make sure that the
> scans aren't off by more than a degree
> or two.
>
> The next test is a sanity check on
> odometry for translation. I'll set up
> rviz the same way with the robot a few
> meters away from a wall. Then, I'll
> drive the robot straight at the wall
> and look at the thickness of the wall
> as reported by the aggregated laser
> scans in rviz. Ideally, the wall
> should look like a single scan but I
> just make sure that it doesn't have a
> thickness of more than a few
> centimeters. If you drive a meter
> towards a wall and get scans spread
> out over half a meter though,
> something is likely wrong with the
> odometry.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sarthak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30192/sarthak/) on 2017-04-28**:
Should I transform laser to Odom or base_link? When I try to run rviz, scans do not coincide with each other . I am using transform as odom-> base_link -> laser

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-05-02**:
If scans do not coincide with each other, you likely have a bad odometry. It is not an issue with the transforms, probably. Your tf chain is just fine.